# Created a virtual environment 'test' in my windows command prompt, but workon test not working in visual studio code? How to fix?

Tags: django, powershell, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Error: PS C:\Users\ARYAN\projects\project1> workon test
workon : The term 'workon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- workon test
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (workon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score 0):

workon didn't work for me also.
So, I tried another way to activate my virtual environment.
Press **Ctrl+Shift+P**
then select **Python: Select Interpreter**.
then choose your environment. If you can't find your environment from the list, you can enter the interpreter paths, for example, "C:\Users\user\venv\Scripts\python.exe"

Finally, reopen VS and voila!

check out their documentation
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-
1.) For Creating Virtualenv

```
py -m venv project_name
```

2.) For activating the Project to work on

```
.\project_name\scripts\activate
```